# How to count clicks for links reliably

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a REST API which has an endpoint for increasing click_count for a certain link. More precisely it is a python based django-rest-framework.

In addition, I have a website which contains links. I would like to count how many times a particular link has been visited (as clicks) from my site by a unique visitor.

I would like to achieve this as reliable as possible. If a single user clicks link multiple times, there would be only one (1) new click for that particular link. So duplicates not allowed. Website is done with angularjs and nodejs.

How do I make API endpoint available for only one increase operation by user and what would be the best practice for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a service between your controller and api you could just add a 'clicked' variable to the service and update it to true the first time you call the api to update the click count.

If you have an log in, you could keep a dictionary on the api with the user ids as keys and a boolean for whether the user has incremented the click_count.

Comment: I was thinking that approach too. Only thing I'm concerned is that the API could be called without the client and that's why basically somebody could make fake calls. Also, I don't have a login so I don't know how to keep track of the variable.